# i dont know where the error is in my code

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error

I'm new to python and cant find where my error is. Python is saying that there is a syntax error but it wont tell me where it is. My task is to make a programme that can count a taxi fare. Here is my code.

```
distance = input("Enter the distance of the taxi ride in kilometers (km): ")
passengers = input("Enter the amount of passengers from 1 to 5: ")

cost = float(distance) + 3 - 1 * 2

if passengers == 5:
    cost = cost * 2
    print("The total cost of the journey is £" cost) 
else:
    print("The total cost of the journey is £" cost)
```

The error is probably something simple but I can't find it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're missing (probably) commas when you try to call the print function with multiple arguments.

Comment: please add the error it shows to your question. that's always important

Comment: `print("The total cost of the journey is £"  + cost) ` You forgot to add the `+`

Comment: " but it wont tell me where it is" Yes, it will. Look at the two lines immediately above the "SyntaxError" message. It will show you the line of code where the error was detected, and then a `^` symbol pointing to the exact position where the error was detected.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to print several things with `print()` function, you need to separate them with commas

try this:

```
print("The total cost of the journey is £", cost)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not concatenating your strings, if you're on python 3.6 or higher use f-strings:

```py
distance = input("Enter the distance of the taxi ride in kilometers (km): ")
passengers = input("Enter the amount of passengers from 1 to 5: ")

cost = float(distance) + 3 - 1 * 2

if passengers == 5:
    cost = cost * 2
    print(f"The total cost of the journey is £ {cost}") 
else:
    print(f"The total cost of the journey is £ {cost}")
```